# Error al insertar datos desde Excel a SQL SERVER con LinqToExcel

Tags: c#, excel, linq

Tengo un ligero traspié al momento de cargar datos a mi base de datos con LinqToExcel. El error ocurre porque mi codificación no cambia a un nuevo bloque de datos, sino que intenta reemplazar los datos del bloque 1.

En pseudocódigo, lo que sucede es básicamente esto:

```
x = 1 //supongan que x representa el bloque 1//
si (nombre != null y apellido != null) entonces
     x.nombre = nombre.txt
     x.apellido = apellido.txt
```

Como verán, me falta una línea de codificación para que 'x' cambie de número para que los nuevos datos sean cargados en un nuevo bloque y que no reemplacen los del bloque 1.

Cuando mi base de datos no tiene ningún dato el código funciona con el primer grupo de datos, pero es a partir del siguiente grupo de datos del Excel que tira error, y sucede en la línea de oContext.DIRIGENTE.Add(oNuevosDatos).

Al poner un punto de interrupción pude ver que aparece un chorizo de código sobre la línea de oContext.DIRIGENTE:

```
{SELECT [Extent1].[IDdirigente] AS [IDdirigente], 
[Extent1].[CiDir] AS [CiDir], 
[Extent1].[NomDir] AS [NomDir], 
[Extent1].[ApeDir] AS [ApeDir], 
[Extent1].[TelDir] AS [TelDir], 
[Extent1].[Barrio] AS [Barrio]
FROM [dbo].[DIRIGENTE] AS [Extent1]}
```

El [Extent1] no cambia cuando llega el segundo conjunto de datos, pero no sé qué hacer para que cambie.

Este es mi código:

```
    private void ImportarAExcel(List<EntidadHojaExcel> oDatos)
    {
        using (var oContext = new PBSEntities1())
        {
            DIRIGENTE oNuevosDatos = new DIRIGENTE();
            foreach (var item in oDatos)
            {
                if (item.IDdirigente != null && item.CiDir != null && item.NombreDir != null && item.ApellidoDir != null && item.TelDir != null && item.Barrio != null)
                {
                    oNuevosDatos.IDdirigente = Convert.ToInt32(item.IDdirigente.Trim());
                    oNuevosDatos.CiDir = Convert.ToInt32(item.CiDir.Trim());
                    oNuevosDatos.NomDir = item.NombreDir.Trim();
                    oNuevosDatos.ApeDir = item.ApellidoDir.Trim();
                    oNuevosDatos.TelDir = item.TelDir.Trim();
                    oNuevosDatos.Barrio = item.Barrio.Trim();
                    oContext.DIRIGENTE.Add(oNuevosDatos);
                    oContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cuando dices *tira un error*, a cuál error te refieres, exactamente? Es una excepción? Cuál es el texto de la excepción?

Comment: El error dice "La propiedad "IDdirigente" es parte de la información de clave del objeto y no se puede modificar". No es importante porque ya descubrí lo que pasa, lo que no sé es cómo resolverlo. Intenté ser claro respecto a eso.

Comment: Qué tal si intentas mover `DIRIGENTE oNuevosDatos = new DIRIGENTE();`, inmediatamente después del `if()`?

Comment: FUNCIONÓ HERMANO GRACIASSSSSSS

Comment: Estudia cómo funciona el `ChangeTracker` de `EF`. Te estaba fallando porque una vez que añadiste la referencia del objeto, `EF` estaba siguiendo los cambios de ese objeto, y cuando intentaste cambiar la llave primaria **te estaba tirando el error que mandaste**. La próxima vez deja la arrogancia atrás, y no escribas *"No es importante"*, o *"Intenté ser claro respecto a eso"*, porque el error trataba **EXACTAMENTE DE ESO**. La solución fue crear una referencia nueva y no reutilizar la existente.